# Is there a method to fix this camera bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time I run around the map and look straight at an object it appears, but when I rotate the camera all the assets in the scene seem to just unload.

I have tried to mess with the camera settings like Clipping Planes and pretty much all the setting in the camera but could not make it work.

The camera is a child of my player objects acting like the eyes of the player(FPS Game) - No script attached to the camera.

Not to bug out when playing randomly unloading chucks of my assets. Requiring it to works as a normal camera would without it bugging out my assets.

[Straight View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkHBB.png)

[Slight angle or just move a little back/forwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuiBF.png)

Comment: Maybe have a look at Occlusion culling settings if the camera is inside the player mesh. Just a guess.

Comment: That is my hunch as well: by rotating the camera, parts of the camera gets inside the model of the player.

Comment: What can I do specifically to fix this in Occlusion settings ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html  But for a quick check just hide your character mesh or put the camera above the mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was kinda obvious but took ages to figure out, turns out the camera was not placed correctly and was to far in-front of the player. Therefor glitching through the walls etc. Stupid mistake but recommend if anyone in future does this **check you camera position is where the player is, not in-front**